# Update rows in an Informix database by incrementing serial numbers

Tags: informix

I have a table in an Informix database, let's say it is called *store*, that looks like:

| serial_num | store_seq |
| --- | --- |
| 381-15 | 82600 |
| 381-15 | 82610 |
| 381-15 | 82640 |
| 381-15 | 82650 |
| 381-15 | 82680 |
| 381-114-1 | 82690 |

I have to update serial_num so that numbers are updated incrementally like this:

| serial_num | store_seq |
| --- | --- |
| 381-15-1 | 82600 |
| 381-15-2 | 82610 |
| 381-15-3 | 82640 |
| 381-15-4 | 82650 |
| 381-15-5 | 82680 |
| 381-114-1 | 82690 |

<sup>*Transcribing a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001141/update-rows-in-informix-databse-by-incrementing-serial-numbers#comment137511852_78001141) into the question:*</sup>

I tried creating a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_store()
    DEFINE counter INTEGER;
    DEFINE temp_serial_num CHAR(20);
    FOREACH cur1 FOR
        SELECT serial_num INTO temp_serial_num FROM store WHERE serial_num = '381-15'
        LET counter = 0;
        WHILE counter < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store WHERE serial_num = '381-15')
            LET counter = counter + 1;
            UPDATE store
               SET serial_num = temp_serial_num || '-' || counter::CHAR
             WHERE CURRENT OF cur1;
         END WHILE;
     END FOREACH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

The result was 381-15-5 in all 381-15 numbers.

NB: The `serial_num` column is a CHAR(16) column; `store_seq` is an INTEGER column.

Comment: informix 14 supports rwo_nuber and window functions https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=expressions-olap-numbering-function-expression

Comment: Why can't you use an auto increment or timestamp column for this purpose?

Comment: I don't have timestamp atribute and serial_num is char type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing up some name mismatches between the code in the comment and the schema of the table, I find your stored procedure doesn't change the data.  However, that's in part because you don't use TRIM to remove the trailing blanks from `serial_num` before appending the new counter.  The TRIM would not be necessary if the `serial_num` column was a VARCHAR instead of a CHAR, but it would do no harm beyond slowing things down a little.

I added an Informix SERIAL column `rec_num` to the table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS store;

CREATE TABLE store
(
    recnum       SERIAL(1000) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    serial_num   CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    store_seq    INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-15', '82600');
INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-15', '82610');
INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-15', '82640');
INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-15', '82650');
INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-15', '82680');
INSERT INTO store VALUES(0, '381-114-1', '82690');
```

A modified procedure takes the `serial_num` to fix as a parameter:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_store;

CREATE PROCEDURE update_store(snum CHAR(16))
    DEFINE counter INTEGER;
    DEFINE temp_serial_num CHAR(20);

    TRACE ON;
    FOREACH cur1 FOR
        SELECT serial_num INTO temp_serial_num FROM store WHERE serial_num = snum
        LET counter = 0;
        WHILE counter < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM store WHERE serial_num = snum)
            LET counter = counter + 1;
            UPDATE store
               SET serial_num = TRIM(temp_serial_num) || '-' || counter::CHAR
             WHERE CURRENT OF cur1;
         END WHILE;
     END FOREACH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

When run, I get the output:

| recnum | serial_num | store_seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1005 | 381-114-1 | 82690 |
| 1003 | 381-15-1 | 82650 |
| 1004 | 381-15-1 | 82680 |
| 1002 | 381-15-2 | 82640 |
| 1001 | 381-15-3 | 82610 |
| 1000 | 381-15-4 | 82600 |

This changes the data in the table, but because no ordering was applied, the rows are not updated in the order of the `store_seq` value, which it appears is the desired result.

A rewritten procedure deals with the ordering problem:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_store;

CREATE PROCEDURE update_store(snum CHAR(16))

    DEFINE counter INTEGER;
    DEFINE old_serial_num CHAR(20);
    -- DEFINE new_serial_num CHAR(20);
    DEFINE old_store_seq INTEGER;

    -- TRACE ON;

    LET counter = 0;
    FOREACH cur1 FOR
        SELECT serial_num, store_seq
      INTO old_serial_num, old_store_seq
      FROM store
     WHERE serial_num = snum
     ORDER BY serial_num, store_seq
        LET counter = counter + 1;
        -- LET new_serial_num = TRIM(old_serial_num) || '-' || counter;
        UPDATE store
           SET serial_num = TRIM(old_serial_num) || '-' || counter
         WHERE serial_num = old_serial_num AND store_seq = old_store_seq;
     END FOREACH;

END PROCEDURE;
```

The `new_serial_num` variable (and the `TRACE ON;` statement) helped identify the missing TRIM problem.

This produces the output:

| recnum | serial_num | store_seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1005 | 381-114-1 | 82690 |
| 1000 | 381-15-1 | 82600 |
| 1001 | 381-15-2 | 82610 |
| 1002 | 381-15-3 | 82640 |
| 1003 | 381-15-4 | 82650 |
| 1004 | 381-15-5 | 82680 |

You can't apply a `WHERE CURRENT OF cur1` clause to an UPDATE when the cursor has an ORDER BY clause on it.  That's why the processing identifies the row to be updated by `serial_num` and `store_req`.